# writing out .dat file in r

Tags: r, save

I have a dataset looks like this:

```
ids <- c(111,12,134,14,155,16,17,18,19,20)
scores.1 <- c(0,1,0,1,1,2,0,1,1,1)
scores.2 <- c(0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0)

data <- data.frame(ids, scores.1, scores.1)

> data
   ids scores.1 scores.1.1
1  111        0          0
2   12        1          1
3  134        0          0
4   14        1          1
5  155        1          1
6   16        2          2
7   17        0          0
8   18        1          1
9   19        1          1
10  20        1          1
```

`ids` stands for student ids, `scores.1` is the response/score for the first question, and `scores.2` is the response/score for the second question. Student ids vary in terms of the number of digits but scores always have 1 digit. I am trying to write out as `.dat` file by generating some object and use those in `write.fwf` function in `gdata` library.

```
item.count <- dim(data)[2] - 1 # counts the number of questions in the dataset

write.fwf(data, file = "data.dat", width = c(5,rep(1, item.count)), 
          colnames = FALSE, sep = "")
```

I would like to separate the student ids and question response with some spaces,so I would like to use 5 spaces for students ids and to specify that I used `width = c(5, rep(1, item.count))` in `write.fwf()` function. However, the output file looks like this having the spaces at the left side of the student ids

```
  11100
   1211
  13400
   1411
  15511
   1622
   1700
   1811
   1911
   2011
```

rather than at the right side of the `ids`.

```
  111 00
   12 11
  134 00
   14 11
  155 11
   16 22
   17 00
   18 11
   19 11
   20 11
```

Any recommendations?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `unite` to `unite` the 'score' columns into a single one and then use `write.csv`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
data %>% 
    unite(scores, starts_with('scores'), sep='')
```

Comment: Hi @akrun, is the `unite` function in `dplyr` ? I am getting this error: `Error in unite(., scores, starts_with("scores"), sep = "") : 
  could not find function "unite"`

Comment: @amisos55. sorry from `tidyr`

Answer (score 1):

with @akrun's help, this gives what I wanted:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
data %>% 
    unite(scores, starts_with('scores'), sep='')

write.fwf(data, file = "data.dat", 
          width = c(5,item.count), 
          colnames = FALSE, sep = " ")
```

in the .dat file, the dataset looks like this below:

```
  111 00
   12 11
  134 00
   14 11
  155 11
   16 22
   17 00
   18 11
   19 11
   20 11
```